# What is the correct punctuation to use when using "like I said" in a sentence?

Tags: punctuation, commas, syntactic-analysis

I don't know how to properly connect the first three words of this sentence to the rest of the sentence:

> Like I said: this is a problem for your doctor, not your drug dealer.

I feel like that colon is incorrect punctuation.  Should it be replaced with a comma?  Or should I use some other punctuation?

Comment: Are you asking about **as vs like** - as in the title, or the punctuation, as in the question?

Comment: The punctuation.  I'm assuming the punctuation is the same for both, which is why I included both.  Sorry, I'll make that more clear in the question.

Comment: The colon is not incorrect, though a dash would be less dated. A comma would also not be incorrect, but would conflict slightly with the second one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> b. In some cases a person's exact words may be treated as either a
>   direct or an indirect quotation, depending on the kind of emphasis
>   desired.
>
> The chairman himself said, “The staff should be told at once that the
>   rumors about a new building have no foundation." [The use of quotation
>   marks emphasizes that these are the chairman's exact words.]
>
> The chairman himself said the staff should be told at once that the
>   rumors about a new building have no foundation. [Without quotation
>   marks, the emphasis falls on the message itself. The fact that the
>   chairman used these exact words is not important]

—Gregg Reference Manual. Tenth Edition. 65.

Also, use *and* instead of the comma for parallel structure: "...**for** your doctor *and* not (**for**) your drug dealer"

CORRECT:

Like I said, this is a problem for your doctor and not your drug dealer.